# Escaping just the querystring part of a url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Rails 3.0.11 app, I am using the normal helper methods to generate the urls for some links (eg:

```
home_url() # for the home page
search_url() # for the search page
```

etc.
)

I am passing in a bunch of parameters that will be used to create a querystring that is then appended to the url.  eg

```
search_url(:text => '123')  # => http://mysite.com/search?text=123
```

Some of these params get a bit more complicated and there are some nested hashes eg

```
search_url(:text => '123', :categories => {:category_1 => 1, :category_2 => 2}) # => http://mysite.com/search?text=123&categories[category_1]=1&categories[category_2]=2
```

The problem I have is how to escape this properly so that it validates (against the W3C HTML validator), particularly with regard to the square brackets.  If I use h(), the ampersands are escaped but it still fails validation on the square brackets.  I can use CGI.escape on the whole string but that will also encode everything before the querystring, including the :// at the start of the address, meaning that the browser will treat it as a relative url when it should be absolute (it needs to be I'm afraid).

I know I could just hack the string up, encode the bits I need and put it back together but it seems like there must be a better way.  Anyone know of one?

Cheers

Adam

Comment: Totally unrelated: ruby doesn't require `()` for method calls.

Comment: @Tass, sometimes it makes it more readable though. Although not when no parameters are passed.

Comment: I know this was long ago, but I have to ask: Did it affect anything other than the validator? In other words, _why_ are square brackets not allowed in query strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in rails 3.2.  Under the hood it's the method Hash#to_query that does the job.

3.0

```
{ :x => { :y => '[]' } }.to_query
=> "x[y]=%5B%5D"
```

3.2

```
{ :x => { :y => '[]' } }.to_query
 => "x%5By%5D=%5B%5D"
```

Perhaps dig into the source to see what the changes are and backport them into your app

Comment: Ah, nice one.  Will have a look to see what's what in there then.  It's nice to know that this has been addressed anyway.  Cheers